# Accepting a comment which automatically transforms into an answer, to save time and money?

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers

I asked a question some time ago: [How do I get a date or datetime out of an SQLite3 row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849726/)

The comment was the holy answer, and I'd like to accept it as good answer. However, I can only accept answers.

Why can't I accept a comment as a good answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Just ask the commenter to add the comment as an answer. Most people will happily do that.

If after several days nothing has happened, add an answer of your own, referring to the comment, and accept it.

Comment: 'add an answer of your own, referring to the comment, and accept it.' that is stealing reputation points.

Comment: @Koning not really: You won't get any reputation for it. But if the user doesn't come back, or for some other reason won't give an answer, it's the only way for you to close the question. As long as you give credit to the original commenter, it's perfectly all right to do. If the commenter comes back later, you can still switch the accept mark

Comment: @Koning: When adding your answer, you could mark it as community-wiki so it doesn't generate reputation for you.

Comment: I agree with @Jon.  When posting someone else's answer it should be marked as community wiki (ie, belonging to the community).

Answer (score 4):

Leave a comment directed at the poster (use @username so they get notification) asking them to repost the comment as an answer.

The only danger with that is that someone else comes along, sees the comment and posts an answer themselves, but hopefully the original poster will see your comment first.