# Improving the comment section with new tools

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mark a comment as answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question)
>   [How should I handle questions which are answered in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-should-i-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments)

Please read before posting as duplicate.**This is not the first time someone asks about this** but I judge this `Feature-Request` didn't get all the attention it should have. Also all the other questions I read about this didn't explain anything.

I've just read this post [How should I handle questions which are answered in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-should-i-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments) and since it's a situation that comes up often, why isn't there a way to simply make this comment become an answer ?

I'm not talking about a way to accept a comment in the comment section that's not the point of this section. But why not add an option to the comments like `Convert this comment to answer` or `Move to the answer section`. This would automatically format the comment into an answer and the comment's owner would be notified that a his comment was changed to an answer. He could of course accept or refuse.He could even maybe get linked to a page to automatically edit the answer (page that looks like the pending edits page)  I'm proposing this for a few things.

- If the user posting the comment does not want to come back and put his comment into an answer, the best answer could be in the comments section.
- I've seen a few posts that were answered only in the comment section which is going against StackExchange Q/A format in my opinion.
- I know users will say "The tool already existsts it's called Copy/Paste" and i'm don't approove this approach either. The user who posted the comment is the one who came up with the answer and is therefore the one who should be awarded the answer.
- If the user with the comment didn't get the chance to come back and formulate is comment as an answer, what is the right delay for the op to take his answer and answer it himself ?
- Maybe I'm not seeing it the right way but I don't think comment that looks like and answer should be permitted in the comment section. For me it's Exactly the same as a comment posted in the answer section. There are two specific sections and that's what they were made for.

I know this question came up before but I don't understand why this is still unhandled because I consider it as a flaw. Another simple solution could be to simply `Tag comment as answer` to seek modertor attention so he could switch it. When I browse StackOverflow or any StackExchange sites I usually  don't bother reading the `All` the comments and I skip directly to the answer section, it bugs me to know that a better answer can be provided as a comment.

Comment: If I leave a comment, it's because I *wanted* it to be a comment, not an answer. It should not be up to *anyone else* to make it an answer, or bother me with extra notifications forcing me to choose whether to agree with people who are trying to make me make it an answer. they can already leave me a comment saying so.

Comment: *"I judge this Feature-Request didn't get all the attention it should have"*...instead of posting a dupe, a bounty on existing proposals might be more appropriate.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA He's asking how to handle this situation. I know how. I'm proposing a new way which I think would be way better. And as I also stated in my question I judge that the other question with the same subject didn't explain anything about "Why" this feature should be added.

Comment: @Bart that's what I would have done if I found a question explaining why this feature should be added. THe problem is the only posts I found were simply asking "Hey let's add a feature that converts comments into answers" with no reasons or ideas

Comment: @AndrewBarber I understand your point. My point on this is I prefer making your comment an answer instead of taking your idea, copy it and put it myself in an answer.

Comment: It overlooks the fact though that comments often make for poor answers. Even if they end up answering the question, they would often need a significant amount of improvement for them to be acceptable answers. Auto-converting them into an answer is undesirable. And that you don't like the idea of taking a comment and rewriting it into an acceptable answer is really a personal issue. If you can make a comment a good answer, that is absolutely fine and you should not hesitate to do so.

Comment: P.s. don't include several feature requests into a single question. Focus on a single one.

Comment: @Bart Well I guess we just don't have to same point of view on this. I don't thing anyone should be taking someone else's comment and put it in his own answer. But that's my opinion. You're right I removed the second one thanks

Comment: Yep, though community consensus from earlier discussions on the topic seems to indicate a "go ahead, that's just fine". Which would make your requested feature unnecessary.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of [How should I handle questions which are answered in the comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/), but it _is_ a duplicate of [Mark a comment as answer to a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555), among others: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66499/, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100729/, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7420/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't like the idea that my comments can be made "into answers" - as a comment is if I'm not sure about something, or perhaps I think a relevant link provides all the information that's required (and the OP just didn't realise the relevant terms to use for searching). So, if it was a direct translation to an answer - then it'd likely be a very low quality answer and not one I'd like to have to my "record" (as it were).

For instance, on this SO post: [What are the available datatypes for 'dtype' with numpy's loadtxt an genfromtxt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997087/what-are-the-available-datatypes-for-dtype-with-numpys-loadtxt-an-genfromtxt)

I was umming and ahhing about whether or not to make it an answer (as the comment had satisfied the OPs requirement) - and eventually decided I would, but at least try to quote related information and a warning. Otherwise, a complete copy/paste of my comment would be a remarkably low quality answer.

Comment: You're totally right. This is something I didn't take into consideration and probably the reason why this is not a feature. Although I still think such a feature would have positive effects on the community, I think there a too many flaws we can already see which makes it unlikely to be added. Thanks